# Replace CHARINDEX return number with 1 if greater than 0

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that looks like this:

```
Select 
CHARINDEX('Test_Value',STRING_AGG(FSD.Test_Value_Field, ';')) As My_Return_Value,
FROM QE_CS CS
...
```

Which returns a value greater than 0 if it's in the aggregated string, however, **I just want it to return 1** if the value is greater than 0. I tried using `IF` like this:

```
Select 
IF CHARINDEX('Test_Value',STRING_AGG(FSD.Test_Value_Field, ';')) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 As My_Return_Value,
FROM QE_CS CS
```

But this returns:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'

Clearly I'm not familiar with using `IF`s in SQL server - how can I get my expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If statement cannot be used in select statement.
Use case statement like this

```
Select 
CASe when CHARINDEX('Test_Value',STRING_AGG(FSD.Test_Value_Field, ';')) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 end As My_Return_Value,
FROM QE_CS CS
```

Comment: Ahh thank you! This works perfectly. I'll mark as correct answer in 5 minutes :)

Answer (score 2):

Yet another option is `sign()`

**Example**

```
sign(CHARINDEX('Test_Value',STRING_AGG(FSD.Test_Value_Field, ';')))
```

Sign() will return -1, 0, 1 or null

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
Select IIF(CHARINDEX('Test_Value',STRING_AGG(FSD.Test_Value_Field, ';')) > 0, 1, 0) As My_Return_Value FROM QE_CS CS
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple conditions to be checked `CASE` is the better option, however you can use 'IIF' function too, official docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
select IIF(CHARINDEX('Test_Value',STRING_AGG('ABC;Test_Value', ';')) > 0 ,1,0) from QE_CS CS
```